# Master details relationship

Tags: master-detail

In the master Details relationship

If the parent recors is deleted child record is also deleted right .

My requiremen is if parent record is deleted child record does not deleted . so how can i acheive this requirement through trigger can i control on detail object(child object) .

Would you please provide me any input on this .

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a master detail relationship ? Do you do any calculation with the children records and then you display them in the parent record? If not you could use a lookup relationship. You will still be able to have the parent child relationship but in this case the object are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration setting when creating the Master Detail relationship

The allow reparenting setting, will allow master detail children to be reparented.

[image]

Comment: Surely only a help if all the child objects are moved to a new parent before the old parent is deleted...

Comment: Thanks..@chris . but this question is how to control on child object in the master detail relationship. this option wil allow me to reparenting child object . but i don't want to reparent the child object. In that case how to achieve this..

Comment: In order to avoid cascade deleting, you need to reparent.  You cannot orphan a child of a master detail, so your only other option would be to reparent it.